# Is there a pipeless, simple one liner to execute a command for each line in a file?

Tags: bash, command

For example,

```
# a demonstration of the functionality
cat dependencies | xargs -n 1 pip install -U  

# expressed as a non-simple, pipeless one liner
awk '{system("pip install -U $0")}' dependencies
```

It seems as if there should be some command for this exact task with only one flag, but I do not know what it is.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you just want:

```
xargs -n 1 pip install -U < dependencies
# or perhaps more readable:
<dependencies xargs -n 1 pip install -U
# and if you don't want to | bash it:
<dependencies xargs -I% -d" " -n 1 bash -c "pip install -U %"
```

Comment: I think the second form is close enough to what I wanted that it doesn't matter anymore

Comment: @Chris: I gave you one that also shell's it without a pipe ^^ but I guess it would be much simpler to | bash the 2nd one indeed. Funnily: on my cygwin: `echo a b c | xargs -I% -d" " -n 1 bash -c "echo __ % __"` works fine untile the last line, wichi outputs: `___ c` and on the next line `bash: line 1: ___: command not found` ... maybe a bug? And my cygwin also bundled "a b c" together without the -d" " ... weird

Comment: I've noticed variance in tools like xargs behavior across systems as well, esp Cygwin.   On mac, I usually have to alias the `g___` (gnu) version of tools because there is so much lag in functionality (old versions and whatnot on the mac os).

Answer (score 3):

For `pip install -U` to be called once with the contents of each line as an extra argument, you need GNU `xargs` and:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -n1 -a dependencies pip install -U
```

Without `-d '\n'` it's each *word* in the file that is passed to `pip install -U`, bearing in mind that `xargs` does its very own quote processing (different from the quote processing in any of the modern shells).

Comment: funnily, as I saw he used -n 1, I thought he wanted each words to be passed, so I added a -d" " to mine (as on my cygwin, it was by defaut passing the whole line even with -n 1 ) ... Implementations (and bugs) do vary

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'd remembered. Apparently the `array` option is not yet present in the `xargs` distributed w/ mac.